# Excel conditional formatting by date

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

When a cell contains both text and a date (ex: 4 YP Next Due Date: 14/01/2022), how can I apply conditional formatting to change the colour of the cell if the date will expire in a years time? 
Worst case, I can move the text in another column and leave the date on its own. Then I use conditional formatting on the column containing the date and try to change the colour of both cells if the date will expire in a years time (assuming this is possible)

Comment: can you give us example with screenshot or cells? What is 4 YP? What date you compare to so the formula knows it will expire in a year time? TODAY date?

Comment: Are the length of text before Date is fixed or it may varry?

Comment: If position of DATE in every cell is fixed the this Can be used,, `=$A1<MID(B1,20,11)` , where `A1` has Date you are testing to determine whether expires or not and `B1` has your String with Date `14/01/22`.

Comment: 4 YP means that an action should be taken every 4 years. The length before the date should be fixed and I can use the formula provided by Rajesh, but if the user change the format (example forget to include a space), the conditional formatting will not work.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest method will consider any length of string around the DATE as well as is flexible with position of the DATE also.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Write *Criteria DATE* is Cell `A2`.
- Select Range to apply Conditional Format.
- Reach to **Conditional Formatting** then **New 
  Rule** and enter this Formula.

  ```
  =$A2>= IFERROR(DATEVALUE(MID(B2,FIND("/",B2)- 2,10 ) ),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

- You may change *Criteria DATE* value & *Logical 
  Operator* as your need.
- If you have DATE at the beginning like 
  `01/04/2019 4 YP Next Due Date`, or no 
  SPACE between DATE & Text, then also 
  this method works and apply Conditional 
  Formatting to Cell/cells, as in Cells 
  `B3`,`B7` and `B9`.

*Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.*